# Issue in setup and deployment project

Tags: setup-deployment

I have the below requirements in set up and deployment project

1. Need to find dot net version available or not
2. If not we ask user to have that
3. if exists we need to check two DLLs are available in GAC or not
4. if not we need to register them

But I don't have any idea as how to proceed....any help!

Answer (score 0):

**Is the .Net Framework installed?**:

Right-click on your setup project, hover on View, and click Launch Conditions:

[image: Open Launch Conditions]

You want to add .NET Framework to your launch conditions:

[image: Add .Net Framework]

After that, you can right-click on .NET Framework and click Properties Window. You can choose the Version number in that window.

**Install assemblies to the GAC**:

Right-click on your setup project, hover on View, and click File System:

[image: Open File System]

Then in that window, right-click on the root node (File System on Target Machine), hover on Add Special Folder, and click Global Assembly Cache Folder:

[image]

Drag your assemblies to this folder to have them installed on the machine. If the correct version is not already there in the GAC, the setup program will install it.